# How to upgrade from Windows 7 to 8 without losing ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 Student Version License?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, installation, license

I have Arc GIS installed in my windows 7 with 1 year license key student version.I have recently installed licensed Arc GIS 1 month ago.Now i want to update my laptop to windows 8.
Now after installing windows 8 does the same license works since the license key is the same?

hoping for response

Eliza

Answer (score 3):

Your license will work definitely. You need to [De-authorize](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40627)  the license from old machine and then authorize it on new machine.

Its very simple process. Don't worry please check support article and let us know if you have any problem..

thanks..

Comment: If she is updating the same laptop to a new version of Windows, why would any de-authorize/reauthorize process need to take place?  The hardware is not changing.

Comment: @GetSpatial Not so much the hardware, but the OS (software). When Windows _updates_, it actually places your entire C: into a "Windows.old" folder. The Windows 8 now probably has none of the old software (like ArcGIS) and is now a fresh installation of Windows. You need to de-activate the license that is attached to the Windows 7 PC so that it can now be authorized for the new Windows 8 PC (after re-installing ArcGIS of course...) regardless of hardware.

Comment: @SaultDon - I did not realize that with a Windows 8 install, you are basically starting from scratch.  Now the need to de/re authorize makes sense.  Thanks Microsoft.